# Strong password regex

Tags: c#, regex

I need strong password validation regex

```
Special Characters - Not Allowed
Spaces - Not Allowed
Numeric Character - At least one character
At least one Capital Letter 
Minimum and Maximum Length of field - 6 to 12 Characters
Repetitive Characters - Allowed only two repetitive characters
```

my Regex is `^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?!.*\s)(?=(?:(\w)(?!\1{2}))+).{6,12}$` 
but it ignores special characters (where to add?)

Please help!

Comment: What led you to believe that a regular expression was the best way to solve this problem?

Comment: Why are you disallowing spaces and special characters? Doesn't that make it a *weak* password regex, instead of a strong one? Your criteria also disallow the user entering a passphrase (a series of words, much longer than a normal password) since you require a digit, no spaces, and limit the length of the password.

Comment: Douglas, special characters allowed only (@) however: *, -, + etc is not allowed special characters.
This is a task :)

Comment: These rules do not create a strong password. They are a long way off. http://www.microsoft.com/protect/fraud/passwords/create.aspx

Comment: When you have a long regex like that it's often worth breaking it down into multiple shorter ones, or inserting line breaks and white space as logical delimiters with the ignore white space flag set.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

```
^(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?!.*(.)\1\1)[a-zA-Z0-9@]{6,12}$
```

- Special Characters - Not Allowed
- Spaces - Not Allowed
- Minimum and Maximum Length of field - 6 to 12 Characters
  Met by `[a-zA-Z0-9@]{6,12}`
- Numeric Character - At least one character
  Met by [positive lookahead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973436/regex-lookahead-lookbehind-and-atomic-groups/2973609#2973609) `(?=.*\d)`
- At least one Capital Letter
  Met by positive lookahead `(?=.*[A-Z])`
- Repetitive Characters - Allowed only two repetitive characters
  I am not sure what you mean by this. The negative lookahead `(?!.*(.)\1\1)` makes sure that no character is allowed to appear more than two times in a row. Substring `aa` is okay, `aaa` is not.
  Make it `(?!.*(.+)\1\1)` to reject repeated substrings of length more than one (like `ababab`) or add `.*` before `\1` to reject non-continuous repeated appearances too.

Comment: Repetitive Characters - i mean: allowed paassword, and not allowed paaassword or passsword. What i need to do in this case?

Comment: I still insist my code is much more readable/maintainable! Bah, regex for everyting and anything.

Comment: @Maxim It seems my understanding was correct. The given regex should do it.

Comment: @Noldorin I kind of agree with you. Regexes and kids are alike - understanding/maintaining someone else's stuff can be a headache. That said, regex is compact and its fun to write them :)

Comment: @Amarghosh: Fun to write indeed, just not to read heh. Thus the downfall of Perl...

Comment: @Noldorin OP asked for regex, and he got one. If you ask me if I'd use (or be allowed to use) this regex in the production code with many people working on it...

Comment: No no, I don't blame you. Just taking the opportunity to have a good rant. :)

Comment: @Noldorin too bad it ended so fast :)

Comment: @Amarghosh, what if I wanted to allow special characters and repetitive characters?

Answer (score 34):

Doesn't sound like a task particularly suited for Regex, since you want to test multiple conditions simultaneously. (You could use multiple regexes, but then normal C# with LINQ is a nicer way to test it.) Try the following function:

```
public static bool IsStrongPassword(string password)
{
    // Minimum and Maximum Length of field - 6 to 12 Characters
    if (password.Length < 6 || password.Length > 12)
        return false;

    // Special Characters - Not Allowed
    // Spaces - Not Allowed
    if (!(password.All(c => char.IsLetter(c) || char.IsDigit(c))))  
        return false;

    // Numeric Character - At least one character
    if (!password.Any(c => char.IsDigit(c)))
        return false;

    // At least one Capital Letter
    if (!password.Any(c => char.IsUpper(c)))
        return false;

    // Repetitive Characters - Allowed only two repetitive characters
    var repeatCount = 0;
    var lastChar = '\0';
    foreach(var c in password)
    {
        if (c == lastChar)
            repeatCount++;
        else
            repeatCount = 0;
        if (repeatCount == 2)
            return false;
        lastChar = c;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Make sure you import `System.Linq` of course, and you're set to go.

Comment: Maybe one could combine the above LINQ approach with a couple of regexps that test stuff that regexps are good at?

Comment: @Maxim: Edited, that's included now. Repetitive characters is the only test I *might* do using regex, but I think the current approach is still fine.

Comment: +1: This method looks more maintainable than using a single regex. IMO even breaking down the single regex into smaller ones would be a step in the right direction.

Comment: @Noldorin char.IsNumeric(c) should be char.IsDigit(c). Just a note of caution for anyone who comes here in future to use this.

Comment: @ashutoshraina: Yeah, I think you're right, cheers. It seems `IsNumeric` allows thousands separators, decimal points, etc. which one doesn't want.

Comment: I can not understand people that only asking "where is my repetative control!!" rather than thank to attentive answers...

Comment: char.IsNumeric should be replaced by char.IsDigit for c# / .NET 4.0

Answer (score 1):

You can search the [regex library](http://regexlib.com/Search.aspx?k=strong%20password)

Answer (score 1):

The following Jquery plugin called pwdMeter works and seems like a cool way to show the user what is and what isn't a strong password.

http://shouvik.net/pwdmeter.php

Comment: this is actually pretty awesome