# Regex to include all special characters

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

I can't seem to find any suitable answer for this.

I need a regex that will make sure that there is at least `one special character`, `one number`, `one upper` and `one lower` and at least 8 long.

I have a few here but for some reason, when I add more characters it doesn't recognize them.

```
ValidationExpression="^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[$@$!%*?&])[A-Za-z\d$@$!%.*?&]{8,}"
```

I want to add every single special character.

Comment: I don't know if I would make this a regex since any of those characters can appear anywhere in your string, so it's not really a pattern.  I would probably just issue separate checks for each requirement of the string to validate.  I know it's not a neat little one-liner, but at least it would be readable.

Comment: Do you mean you want to match any chars but whitespace? Replace `[A-Za-z\d$@$!%.*?&]` with `\S`

Comment: I have two input strings and these are checking that at least one of the above characters exist in the input string. But i want to add all of the special characters available to check that at least the user has used at least one of them.

Comment: So in essence, i want to add !"£$%^&*()_+{}:@~<>?|-=[];'#,./\ also

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Checking strings for a strong enough password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12899876/checking-strings-for-a-strong-enough-password)

Answer (score 0):

Please try to avoid long and complex regular expressions, because it would be hard to understand and modify them in future. Instead define a few simple and straightforward Regex, then combine it with c# code

```
var hasLowercaseChar = new Regex("[a-z]");
var hasUppercaseChar = new Regex("[A-Z]");
var hasDigitChar = new Regex("[0-9]");
var hasSpecialChar = new Regex("\\$!\\^-@%&\\.\\*");

var input = "" // your input string here
var passwordIsValid = hasLowercaseChar.IsMatch(input)
    && hasUppercaseChar.IsMatch(input)
    && hasDigitChar.IsMatch(input)
    && hasSpecialChar.IsMatch(input)
    && input.Length >= 8;
```

In above example each regular expression is simple and even if you not sure what it should match you can infer this from variable names

Answer (score 0):

The following regex should do the trick: 
    `^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*\W)[\S]{8,}$`

Answer (score 0):

Try Regex: `(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[$@!%*?&!"£$%^&*()_+{}:@~<>?|=[\];'#,.\/\\-])[A-Za-z\d$@!%*?&!"£$%^&*()_+{}:@~<>?|=[\];'#,.\/\\-]{8,}`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/gaxIo3/1)