# Regular expression for password validation without whitespaces C#

Tags: regex

Password must contains minimum of 8 symbols.

min 2 digits in any order,

min 1 special in any order character and

must not allow whitespaces.

I have something like this:

```
(?=.*\d.*\d)(?=.*[$/@:?{~!^`\[\]]{1,}).{8,}
```

UPD solution:

```
(?=[^\s]*\d){2}(?=[^\s]*[$/@:?{~!^`\[\]]){1,}[^\s]{8,}
```

Comment: exactly 2 digits or min 2 digits? and the same for the special character

Comment: Sorry,min 2 digits, updated

Comment: refer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19491670/regular-expression-for-password-at-least-2-digits-and-one-special-character-and

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Strong password regex](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3131025/strong-password-regex)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would change the `.` into `\S`, if your language supports negated classes

```
(?=\S*\d){2}(?=\S*[$/@:?{~!^`\[\]]){1,}\S{8,}
```

or into `[^\s]`, if it does not

```
(?=[^\s]*\d){2}(?=[^\s]*[$/@:?{~!^`\[\]]){1,}[^\s]{8,}
```

Comment: @Chase Since `\S{8,}` will whatever check for whitespaces, no need to use `\S` in the lookaheads. The `^` and `$` anchors are also missing.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another one:

```
^(?=(?:.*\d){2})(?=.*[$/@:?{~!^`\[\]])\S{8,}$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/iJSjzieVB-rZgFrP)

Answer (score 0):

```
^(?!.*\s.*)(?=.*\d.*\d)(?=.*[$/@:?{~!^`\[\]]{1,}).{8,}$
```

Anchoring it to the start and end, with a negative lookahead for the whitespace

Answer (score 0):

here is my suggestion:

```
^(?!\d+$)(?![$/@:?{~!^`\[\]]+$)[$/@:?{~!^`\[\]\d]{8,}$
```

NOTES： you need find another way to check at least 2 digits

Answer (score 0):

```
 (?!.*?\s+.*?)
```

Just add this to your existing regex.A negative lookahead detecting one or multiple spaces.