# RegExp pass validation

Tags: javascript, regex, passwords

Start with letter, at least one upper and lower case characters, at least one digit, 6-12 charachers, and no more then 3 consecutive same characters

I write this, but not good enough.. .Any ideas?

```
/^[A-Za-z] (?=.*\d) (?=.*[a-z])(?!.*(.)\1\1)(?=.*[A-Z]).{6,12}$/
```

Comment: There are a lot of password regex'es already available. Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3131025/strong-password-regex for instance.

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
^(?=^[A-Za-z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?!.*(.)\1\1).{6,12}$
```

- `(?=^[A-Za-z])` starts with a letter
- `(?=.*\d)` contains a number
- `(?=.*[a-z])` contains lower case letter
- `(?=.*[A-Z])` contains UPPER case letter
- `(?!.*(.)\1\1)` not 3 consecutive char
- `.{6,12}` from 6 to 12 long